# Framelayout Inside the RecyclerView

Tags: android

This is my code:

outer.xml

```
<constraintLayout>
    <imageView/>
    <recyclerView>
    </recyclerview>
    <textview/><textview/><textview/>
</constraintLayout>
```

inner.xml

```
<frameLayout>
    <imageView width="match_parent" height="match_parent" scale=centerCrop/>
    <textView text1/>
   <textView text2/>
    <textView text3/>
</frameLayout>
```

I have a image between width: 640/height: 960px and w:480/h:720px but the Image doesn't fill the whole screen... especially the smaller one... 
I also tried to use fill_parent and or remove the centerCrop value but nothing or worse happened...

Comment: Try 
<imageView width="match_parent" height="match_parent" scale=fitXY/>
in scale type of image view.

Comment: or use scaleType=centerCrop on Imageview.

Comment: please can you show me your XML code for more understand

Comment: I tried centerCrop since the first day but smaller image doesnt fill the screen, and when I viewed it on the tablet, the image is the same size in the phone...
I expect the image follow the size of the screen, while other textviews is above them